# DatePicker Plugin Made by 2Amigo in yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I downloaded DatePicker Plugin using composer in Yii2 and I can see the file in my vendor directory. The plugin is *2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget* you can see it on GitHub.
My problem is when I make a model name COMPANIES and I made a CRUD, I want to use DatePicker in my CRUD and here is my _form.php file :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
?>
<div class="companies-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'logo')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?=
        $form->field($model, 'company_start_date')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
                'inline' => false,
//                'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'format' => 'y-m-d',    
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_created_date')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_status')->dropDownList([ 'active' => 'Active', 'inactive' => 'Inactive', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

but when I click on *Create* in my grid it gives me the following error:

> Error
>   (#1) An internal server error occurred. The above error occurred while
>   the Web server was processing your request.
>
> Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you got more error details like in `runtime/logs/app.log`?

Comment: @Bizley i'm sorry , i'm new in Yii . i don't get your means

Comment: what is  `runtime/logs/app.log` @Bizley

Comment: Do you log errors like in `frontend/runtime/logs/app.log`? If not - error details should appear in your server error log file. Without the details it's hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: @Bizley i use this datepicker in Baisc now (the above code was for adv yii2) and it gives me this Error : **Class 'dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker' not found** but i can see that class in my vendor directiry . what is the problem , becasue this kind of problems occur for me a lot of times in yii (not found the class blaw blaw)

Comment: Are you using composer to install extensions?

Comment: @Bizley yes . i use Php Storm and it has a Terminal inside of it and i install things by order like : composer require blaw blaw blaw

Comment: Check if there is `"2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget" : "~1.0"` added in your `composer.json` file in root Yii 2 project folder.

Comment: @ali Can you use the backward slash while including the date picker class like this - use \dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;

Comment: @Bizley well , "2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget": "*", this is added to my jason file . when i want to add "~1.0" it gives me error about minimum-stability

Comment: @ManikandanS as you see in my code , i write backward slash :(

Comment: @ali I mean to say use like this -  use \dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;  backward slash will be at beginning also.